# Send Email using MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am beginner to MVC, have to implement a functionality to send mail in a MVC application.

Below is my code.

View :

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID)

<input type="submit" name="name" value="SendMail" />
@{ Html.RenderAction("SendMail", "PagesController");

}
```

Controller code : PagesController

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendMail(EmailModel model)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com");
        msg.To.Add(model.EmailID);
        msg.Subject = "Welcome To REBAR Mobile Showcase";
        msg.Body = "Hi," + Environment.NewLine + @"Welcome to REBAR Mobile Showcase. Please click on the below link : https://ciouishowcase.accenture.com/mobile/m"
            + Environment.NewLine + "Regards," + Environment.NewLine + "CIO Design Agency";
        msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc", "passwrod", "Dir");
        client.Host = "email.abc.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.Send(msg);
        return View();
    }
```

Model : EmailModel

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a few questions here :

1. How should I call this method on click of send link button.
2. I want to apply style as well on the text box & sendmail link. How should I do it with these type of controls?

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID)

1. Am I following MVC Standards? If not, where.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally, if you have unrelated issues, in your case, one about an MVC action and another about styling, you should break up your question into multiple ones.  This makes it easier to be answered by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("SendMail", "PagesController");

}
```

just change the `BeginForm` method to this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Pages", FormMethod.Post)
```

and that will force the `submit` button to `POST` to the method you've described in your controller. It matches up the controller name `Pages` to `PagesController`, then it matches up the action name **coupled with** the method type and finds this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendMail ...
```

And as far as applying styles, that's done via basic HTML and CSS. You could use something like:

```
form input[type="text"] {

}
```

to style the `text` input for example.

Answer (score 3):

1. In your view, you don't need the RenderAction-call, but you need to pass the correct action to your begin-form
2. Applying styles: You can pass in a dynamic object with the attributes you want on the element. In this case I added a class-attrbute (which you then have to style with CSS)

   ```
   @using (@Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Pages"))
   {    
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID, new() {@class="somecssclass"})

       <input type="submit" name="name" value="SendMail" />
   }
   ```